# requesting double value always shows 0.00

Tags: php, mysql, double, number-formatting

i try to display a 'double' value from the MySQL column, i am converting it using `number_format()` but the whole time i get is 0.00 as answer.
My code;

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$a = $_GET['a'];

// ...

if ($a == "balance") {
    $querys= "SELECT balance FROM users WHERE Username='$user'";
    $results=  mysql_query($querys);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_row($results);
    $bfloat = number_format($rows['balance'], 2);
    echo $bfloat;
}

?>
```

The convertion is working, the only problem is that the answer is 0.00 and not the balance that the user has. Example; 1.37

Comment: done basic debugging, like `var_dump($rows['balance'])` to see what's in there before you start formatting? And you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: *sidenote:* You might want to close that SQL injection hole (username with `'` in it) [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @MarcB I am not vulnerable to SQL injections since all spaces get converted to _ an underscore upon registering/logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
$bfloat = number_format($rows[0], 2);
```

instead of

```
$bfloat = number_format($rows['balance'], 2);
```

because you use `mysql_fetch_row` function. If you want to use `$rows['balance']` you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` function to get data and not `mysql_fetch_row`

Of course you shouldn't use mysql functions any more (there are deprecated) and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining now i understand the logical, since i only request one column and probably the counting starts at 0 its the balance column. :D